# Zend MongoDB implementation

Tags: mongodb, zend-framework2

I am attempting to integrate Zend with MongoDB. I think I am almost there, but I need some help to complete the task. I am new to both zend and mongo, but reasonably experienced with PHP and MySQL.

Some details:

My Zend project is based on the skeleton tutorial at http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html. This works fine on my computer, but is mysql-based.

I have installed MongoDB. I can write nosql on the command line and I can instantiate a MongoClient object in a PHP script, so those things seem to work and talk to each other.

I want to use mongo instead of mysql, and I have implemented Doctrine. I have no idea what Doctrine does, and I've been through several searches to try and find how to run mongo commands in zend. These facts lead me to conclude that I don't know what I'm doing.

So to the specifics of my question:

- As I understand it, I should be instantiating a mongo object somewhere. If so, where should I put the instantiation in zend?
- If not, presumably I need an existing instantiation of the mongo object to run various find/save commands from inside the model class, so if that's true, how do I access the existing mongo object?

Thanks for any help, and clarification questions are equally welcome.

**Edited 13/12/2012 for clarification.**

With the given answers it seems I am on the right track, and I can further clarify what I need:
Looking at the [Doctrine Documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html) linked below, I am still unclear where the document manager instantiation is supposed to occur. I would have expected it to go into a more generic location which is run on every page load. Also, most of the tutorials I find seem to refer to a file structure different given from the skeleton application, so when they say to put certain things in certain places, I'm not sure where they mean. For example, I keep seeing references to bootstrap files, but my only bootstrap files are in test directories.

My questions are these:

- What code do I need to add into the indexAction function (which definitely responds when I go to the correct URL) if I simply want to print_r all the documents in a collection?
- Do I need to add any other code elsewhere, if so where, and what code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the different bits and what they do, working from the bottom up:

**mongodb**: data persistance

**doctrineODM**: Object Document Mapper. This maps mongo documents to php objects. It means you don't have to worry about doing any calls against mongo directly - you just work with plain old php objects. To use doctrineODM you need to define your model classes, and get the hang of using the DocumentManager - suggested, the Doctrine docs are quite good.

**doctrineMongoODMModule**: A module that integrates doctrine with zf2. The main thing it does is allow you to configure doctrine using zf2 config style, and gives you access to the DocumentManager via the zf2 ServiceManager. (I does quite a few other things too, but they are the main ones)

**zf2 (mvc)**: Lets you define an interface so other things (like a web client) can manipulate your documents.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. It's good to hear it from somebody in terms specific to my requirements. This will be helpful for me to refine my question later. I suspect I need to know where config code files should be going.

Answer (score 0):

There is brilliant module [doctrine-mongo-odm-module](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMongoODMModule) for mongoDB access.
Just add to composer.json

```
"require": {   
....
"doctrine/doctrine-mongo-odm-module": "dev-master",
....
```

[Doctrine documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html) should help how to use it.

Comment: That's great, thanks for that. I did that, so I'm clearly on the right track. I understand better what I need to know so I'll have to refine my question.